# Actual non-axial airflow (sideslip) for a propeller driven aircraft

Tags: propeller, engine, airspeed, model-aircraft, sideslip

I am making a propeller model for a two-engine propeller driven aircraft (like a Dornier 228). I have expanded my model to include the non-axial airflow as well. $$ $$
By non axial airflow, I mean that the air does not strikes the forward moving aircraft straight along the propeller axis $v_x$, but in some angle. Imagine the propeller rotating along the $v_x$ axis in the figure below:

[image: Components of free stream velocity]

I want to generate the data from the model for some meaningful range of the sideslip angles ($\alpha ,\beta$). I could obviously choose a range [$-90^\circ 90^\circ$]. But the simulation time increases exponentially with such a large number of datapoints.
$$ $$
Generally, I think, for a propeller driven aircraft, it should not be that high. I was thinking to take a range of [$-15^\circ 15^\circ$]. $$ $$
Can anyone who has a bit of experience in these kind of aircraft, please suggest a practical range of the sideslip angles that is generally encountered.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Are you simulating only the propeller, or also the engine and aircraft it will be mounted on?

Comment: I am simulating only the propeller

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the thrust-generating operation of the propeller, then yes, -15 to +15 degrees is sufficient as outside that range, the propeller blade will stall and be ineffective at generating thrust. For that reason, operation outside that region is not attempted practically. If you want to ignore reverse thrust i.e. focus on positive thrust only, then you can restrict yourself to only positive values. If however you want to include feathering operation of the propeller also, then you will have to take the high positive (+90) values into account.

Comment: Are you sure that the blades will be stalled? I'm asking because in a helicopter, the main rotor as well as the tail rotor are almost 90° to the freestream airflow, but they are not stalled. So why would a propeller be stalled under similar conditions?

Comment: @AdityaSharma Yes, Aditya. So there are a few angles to be taken care of here. Let q,d,o be a dextral orthogonal basis fixed to the acft with q pointing to starboard, d pointing forward and o 'upward'. In the case of the prop, the blades have a circumferential velocity in the q-o plane and the acft's velocity is along the d-axis (treating alpha as small). Consider a prop spinning CCW viewed from front and one blade instantaneously aligned along the o-axis. The blade velocity relative to acft is +q, so the blade's total velocity is 1st quadrant in q-d plane. Contd

Comment: The angle of attack at the blade is the angle made by the chord line of the blade with this velocity vector. Since blade is airfoil, it generates lift if and only if this angle is small. Hence the blade chord must make a 'yaw' angle with the o-axis so that its chord is close to the total velocity mentioned above. To answer your helicopter questions. The main rotor is approximately in the q-d plane. Circumferential velocity has q and d components while acft velocity is d. Again, at any point on the rotor, the total velocity is a combination of q and d. Contd

Comment: Now recall the formal definition of AoA. It is the angle from the chord-normal projection of the airfoil's velocity vector to the chord line. Consider a blade instantaneously along the positive d-axis, rotating CCW viewed from positive o. This is the configuration where there is greatest chance of confusion. Then, its total velocity has a -q and +d component. If the blade lies flat then span, chord and normal are +d, -q and +o respectively. AoA is angle from -q to -q which is zero. Give the blade a small 'bank' about d and you have a small angle of attack, not a stall.

Comment: Lastly for the helicopter tail rotor, mounting plane is d-o, circumferential velocity is also d-o and acft velocity adds d. If the blades are flat, circumferential velocity and acft velocity are both in the plane of the chord and span, so AoA is again zero, and a twist of the blades generates a small AoA, equal to the amount of the twist.

Comment: Again, there are some approximations in the above but I have tried to present the picture without going into rotation and projection matrices. It DOES remain true that manoeuvres such as rapid pitch rate and rapid yaw rate might send the main, respectively tail rotor blades into a stalled condition, by adding a significant velocity component along the normal to the airfoil. Perhaps this is a factor which limits the angle change rate, but I am speculating wildly here [unlike in what I said before ;-)]. Further comments, clarification etc most welcome

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed analysis, but I'm still not convinced that the propeller blades would be stalled at $α$/$β$ = 90°, while the helicopter rotor is not stalled under the same conditions. Take a look at [this video](https://youtu.be/QYijn_PTshk?t=1m42s) of an RC stunt plane; the propeller appears to remain un-stalled at quite high "side slip" angles.

Comment: Here we need to distinguish between the sideslip of the aircraft as a whole and the sideslip of the individual propeller blades. What Neelabh is asking about is the fact that, because of the rotation of the props plus the translation of the whole acft, the air impinges on the blades at an angle. Again, to be more precise, at the instant the blade is lined up along o, the blade's total velocity is in the first quadrant between q and d. If the plane had been stationary then this velocity would have been +q only.

Comment: On the other hand, in the video extract you showed (amazing stunt by the way), the sideslip of the aircraft is adding a velocity component which, for if the blade were to lie flat, is spanwise or chordwise depending on its position. But it is not normal. So, when for the definition of AoA, we take the chord-normal projection of this velocity, the span component is eliminated and once again we have the angle from the chord to the chord, which is zero. Now twist the blade and we have a small, controllable AoA which can be chosen in the non-stall range. Is it clearer now ?

Comment: As a nitpick, alpha/beta=90 degrees is not an optimal notation. The ratio of the two angles is dimensionless and although radian is dimensionless and convertible to degree, expressing a ratio in degrees is in general not a good practice. Hence I have not attempted that part of the question. If on the other hand you wanted to convey something else, for instance "+" instead of "/", please let me know and I will address that aspect too.

Comment: @Aditya I just want to clarify that my all discussion of blade stall relates to the parameter beta of Neelabh's question. The parameter alpha will not cause blade stall but will cause wing stall of the whole acft if exceeding the stall range. In propeller applications though, it is beta which is primarily important and that was what I am focussing on. I look forward to your reply to the rest of the stuffs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "sideslip of the individual propeller blades". In his question, Neelabh says that "*air does not strikes the forward moving aircraft straight along the propeller axis $v_x$ , but in some angle.*" Assuming that the propeller axis is coincident with the aircraft's longitudinal axis, it would imply that the sideslip angle for the propeller is same as that for the rest of the aircraft.

Comment: Also, by $α/β$, I meant to say $α$ or $β$. As far as the propeller is concerned, the angle of attack is indifferent from the sideslip angle because the propeller (for all practical purposes) is a symmetrical body. Aerodynamically for the propeller, a 90° AoA is indifferent from a 90° sideslip.

Comment: @AIC12302 Hi, thanks for the answer. I am taking feathering position into account. But I think it doesn't affect the sideslip angle range. At feathering, blade angle/pitch = $90^\circ$. But the air will flow as same as in any other blade angle, for e.g in $30^\circ$. Am I getting something wrong?